# Selecting specified columns form DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable object which is read from Excel speradsheet. Since the spread sheet has blank columns. I want to get rid of the blank columns in my DataTable retaining only the columns which have header data. Any better approaches rather than reading though each column?

I use C# 3.5.

Comment: How do you read the Excel spreadsheet ? Maybe you can do something in there . . .

Answer (score 0):

You can better use "OleDbConnection" rather than looping through each columns to fetch data.
It will avoid the blank columns

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from YourTable", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Our earlier implementation had exactly the same thing...! but this works only if Excel is installed on the server which is not the case...

Comment: you dont need to install Excel to work. just download the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components  from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en